# Insert (or Update) Cursor setting value to None not honored when field has a default value

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, default-value, cursor

To set a field to `null`, the `InsertCursor` or `UpdateCursor` is setting the value to `None`.

Here is a sample for the `UpdateCursor`:

```py
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(test_fc, ['SERVICEINDICATOR'], """"OBJECTID" = 1""") as uCur:
for row in uCur:
    row[0] = None
    uCur.updateRow(row)
```

The field allows nulls but has a default value. When setting the value to `null`, it always sets to the default.

In other words, if the default is '`N`', setting the field to None results in the row having '`N`'.

How can the cursors respect the `None`/`Null` request?

This is an Oracle SDE database (so the answer to [arcpy.UpdateCursor setting value to 0 instead of Null](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164086) does not apply) and ArcMap 10.1

Comment: I'd have to think that was designed behavior.  Setting a default value tells the software you won't accept a NULL, and to use that instead.  How could it possibly know you mean "except in this case"?

Comment: @Vince Interesting thought!  Oddly, on the InsertCursor, if the field is not specified, the value is null, which is where I would think it will fill in the default instead.

Comment: If you had set the default value in Oracle, certainly, but it takes a sophisticated insert to realize it needs to add unspecified columns.

Comment: You *could* create a trigger to convert "Q" to a NULL, then set "Q" when you mean NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is according to design.

Keep in mind that there are at least two places where defaults can be applied:

- In ArcObjects through the field definition
- In the RDBMS at the column definition

DA UpdateCursor is interacting with the former, so when you pass in a `None`, ArcObjects sees this, notices that the field has a default, and assigns the default value to the column.  If the default-laden field is *not* on the column list, ArcObjects does *not* look at the value, so a NULL results (unless the database has a default, or a NOT NULL column is not referenced in the insert, at which point an error would be raised).

The only way to immediately get a NULL added to a row where the field has a default is to use an insert trigger, so that each time the third value of the legal domain {'Y','N','Q'} appears, a NULL is populated where the Q would have been.  If some delay is permitted between insert and availability, then there are a large number of options for doing batch updates.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior with ArcPy DA cursors was caused by [BUG-000091314: When using the data access module and an update curs..](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5MTMxNA==).  Esri finally addressed this defect in Pro 3.1 through the introduction of a new `explicit` parameter in the ArcPy DA [InsertCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm) and [UpdateCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

Modifying the OP's code using the new parameter to force nullable fields to accept NULL:

```py
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(test_fc, ['SERVICEINDICATOR'], """"OBJECTID" = 1""", explicit=True) as uCur:
    for row in uCur:
        row[0] = None
        uCur.updateRow(row)
```